# Merge two tables ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only if new value is not null

Tags: mysql, merge, notnull

I have to  merge two tables  and update on duplicate key only if new value is not null.
I tried the code below with no success
Can anyone help?
Thanx!

```
INSERT
INTO    table1
SELECT  * FROM    temp  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  table1.tel = coalesce(temp.tel,table1.tel),
  table1.fax = coalesce(temp.fax,table1.fax)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Were any rows inserted, did the query fail (with an error)? Which is the part that fails. Your query looks just fine.

Comment: table1 didn't change at all or changed unexpectedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem may be the way you are referring to the values in your update clause. The following may work better:

```
INSERT
INTO    table1
SELECT  * FROM    temp  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  table1.tel = coalesce(values(tel),tel),
  table1.fax = coalesce(values(fax),fax)
```